# Selecting a data from column

Tags: java, sql

My table is as below

```
ID    Name   City
-----------------

1     abc    Mumbai
2     def    Delhi
3     xyz    bangalore
```

I want to write a query as

```
String query= select Name from table where (?)
```

what should come in the where clause if I want to select city Delhi if the input is an ID?

Comment: This is very basic SQL. Please take a tutorial first.

Comment: don't miss double quotation

Comment: no Id is not primary key. I am assigning id's manually

Comment: then there can be multiple value for same id ryt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should frame it as ,

```
String query= "select City from table where ID=2";
```

The general syntax  select (COLUMN 1 , COLUMN 2) from table where condition; also you can use `*` to select the entire row.

will return `Delhi` in the resultset. hope you are using jdbc

Answer (score 1):

```
select Name from table where id=2;
```

or

```
select City from table where id=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Where id = IdInputVar
```

Should work